# How can I access all the properties in one tab in an umbraco node?

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco

Is there a way that I can access tabs in umbraco using C#? I am trying to loop through each property in a particular tab so that I can show/hide that section of the website depending on whether that tab has content in it or not.

I have tried `ContentType.Tab.GetTab();` but that takes an id and I can't find a tab id anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: why you want the properties grouped by the Tab?

Comment: because I've got 4 sections that have similar content so it's better for the user if they are separated, otherwise it'll just be a huge list of fields for them to fill in and could be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `getVirtualTabs` method then loop foreach property inside that tab

```
Node current = Node.GetCurrent();
DocumentType dt = DocumentType.GetByAlias(current.NodeTypeAlias);
if (dt != null) {
    foreach(var tab in dt.getVirtualTabs) { //get all tabs
        foreach(var propertyType in tab.PropertyTypes) { //loop through each property inside the Tab
            // propertyType.Name
            //....write here your code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks, I'll give that a try. Is there a way that I can specify a tab?

Comment: you can check the properties of "propertyType" like the name or ID